# Send image to printer scale 1

Tags: c#, image, winforms

There are many posts about this but, I didn't find what I need exactly.

In my application, users scan images and take some measures on it in using centimeters.

The tools is calibrated so that those measures in centimeters correspond to the same size when the image is printed. After scanning them, users can print the image with the taken measures.

The objective is printing them in scale 1:1. That is to say, if we measure on the paper by a ruler, we should see exactly the same values in centimeters as displayed on the screen.

The images are always 37.8 pixel per cm.

In a WinForms application, I added a PrintDocument and a PrintDialog and I set the document property of the PrintDialog to my PrintDocument. Then, I call that form with the image path to print:

```
 public string ImagePath { get; set; }
 public Form1(string imagePath)
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ImagePath = imagePath;
 }
 public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         printDocument1.Print();
     }
 }

 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, 
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
 {
     System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(this.ImagePath);
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(img.Width * 1.11), Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * 1.093)); 
     this.Close();
 }
```

The solution above works fine on my pc Full HD and a zoom factor of 100%. However, if:

- there is a different zoom factor, for example 125%
- the resolution is not Full HD

Then the measures in centimeters when printing the images do not correspond to what is shown on screen. For example, in the image below, the 15 cm line gets shorter when there is a zoom factor:

[image: example image]

Is there a dynamic way to calculate and ajust the parameters when there is a different zoom factor and a different screen resolution so that the image printed on paper presents always the same measures?

Comment: I don't understand, is the "Resize" window shown in your picture part of your application as well?

Comment: I also think that the Zoom factor and the Full/Not Full HD are different problems, you shouldn't mix them.

Comment: Hi Jarmanso7, thanks for replying. I realised that the problem was different. I will edit my question to better explain because with the given parameters it is not clear.